# Changing color of the dots in Geom_Point

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im new to R and I have been trying to make this work but I dont seem to know how. Apologies if this is some easy fix that I'm missing.

I'm trying to make my dots in this plot a different shade of green.

Here is the code:

```
p = ggplot(data = swissnew, aes(x = Fertility, y = Education))
p = p + geom_point(color = "Green", size = 4, alpha = .3)
```

I then tried to run this

```
p + scale_color_manual(values = "00FF33")
```

It runs but no change seems to be happening to the actual plot when it shows.

Comment: Try `p+geom_point(color="00FF33",size=4,alpha=.3)`

Comment: @ViníciusFélix This helps! At first it wasnt working but I forgot to put the hashtag "#" before it so now it works. Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: One of you should post what worked as an answer.

Comment: Okay cool. I will.

Answer (score 1):

This was what I ended up using.

```
p+geom_point(color="#00FF33",size=4,alpha=.3)
```

Forgetting to use the hashtag will not allow the hexadecimal code to work.

Thanks a lot guys!